# 301 redirect not working properly (my guess is b/c I'm dealing with Add-on domains)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a primary/account domain (PrimaryDomain.com) and a couple add-on domains (AddOnDomain1.com and AddOnDomain2.com) I've recently switched the content from AddOnDomain1.com to AddOnDomain2.com and I want everything to redirect to the exact same location (folders, files, images, etc.)

Here's what I have in .htaccess of my public_html folder (for PrimaryDomain.com):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.AddOnDomain1\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://AddOnDomain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^AddOnDomain1\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://AddOnDomain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It trys to redirect but here's what happens (with an image as an example). When I enter:

http://AddOnDomain1.com/img/logo.png

It redirects to:

http://AddOnDomain2.com/**AddOnDomain1**/img/logo.png

Notice how it adds that folder (in bold)?...which of course is the add-on domain directory name. Anyone aware of a fix for this scenario?

Comment: Can you double check if you pasted your rules correctly (there is `.com.com` in the second condition, and also check if there is a `%1` somewhere maybe

Comment: @DusanBajic The extra .com was/is not in my .htaccess (I just inadvertently added it when I posted here). And no, there is no %1. What else can I try?

Comment: Your rules are strange: you are redirecting if HTTP_HOST is **not** addondomain1? Also, that strange redirect you get is not from these rules, there is some other `.htaccess` involved here (is there one in addondomain2 document root?)

Comment: @DusanBajic There is nothing relevant in the .htaccess file for addondomain2 (just the default code that Wordpress puts there). What else to try?

Comment: Well. try `curl -v http://AddOnDomain1.com/img/logo.png` and look what is in `Location:` response header

Comment: I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: if you are on windows, download and install `curl` and type that command in cmd window, then look at output and find the line starting with `Location`(on mac and linux you should already have it so just type that in terminal)